# C# Windows Forms App - how to detect non-forms window closing

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I have a Windows forms application that uses OpenCV to display videos.  The video display window is created when I call this OpenCV call

```
CvInvoke.Imshow(winname, frame);
```

`frame` is a single frame of video.

The call returns nothing so I don't know the handle of the Window that the call created.  What I do know is the title of the window. I found this code to that finds the handle of the window:

```
private IntPtr FindWinHandle(string winName)
{
    IntPtr hWnd = IntPtr.Zero;
    foreach (Process pList in Process.GetProcesses())
    {
        if (pList.MainWindowTitle.Contains(winName))
        {
            hWnd = pList.MainWindowHandle;
        }
    }
    return hWnd; //Should contain the handle but may be zero if the title doesn't match
```

The question then is..... **how do I use this IntPtr to find when the window is attempted to be closed using the "X" button??**

Currently, pressing the X closes the window, but pops right back up when the next frame of video is displayed.  It appears window IS closing the window but doesn't "stay closed" because of the next `Imshow` call.

This function does work with my code and I am able to find the IntPtr that corresponds to my window.  BUT, it takes > 500ms and that throws off my video sync.  I can't afford that long of a call.

I think an entirely different approach is needed.  OpenCV doesn't expose this info anywhere??

Comment: I think you are going to have to resort to a global mouse event hook to intercept all mouse clicks, and see if they are over that window/control that you want.

Here's some resources:

 - https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/26913842/Global-Mouse-Hook-to-find-Windows-Handles-in-C.html
 - https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/SamTomato/clicking-a-button-in-another-application/

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the time to mock up a full solution, but be sure to come back and answer your own question if you end up working something out!

Comment: My application DOES own the window by the way.  It is just that OpenCV creates it on my behalf and manages it.  I'm assuming that I can manipulate it once I get the handle, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Since your application *does* own the window, can you just use a [Control.FromIntPtr](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.fromhandle(v=vs.110).aspx) call to get a reference to it, then subscribe to the OnClosing event?

```
var control = Control.FromIntPtr(intPtr);
Form form = control as Form;
if (form is null) 
    form = control.FindForm();
form.OnClosing += //your code here
```

Also, if your application owns the form, can you find it using `Application.OpenForms` instead of using native stuff?

Comment: THANK YOU!!  And thanks for the OpenForms tip!  Searching for the window using the technique I posted takes over 500ms, more time than I have.  Will post if this solves my problem. Sounds like it should!